# How to disable animated blank avatar on login screen

Tags: login-screen, sonoma

When I boot up my Mac running 14.1, I see my the icon I used when I migrated from my older Mac running a much older Mac OS. Then a smaller circle with a blank avatar -- the gray featureless headshot over a dark gray circle -- will peek momentarily out from behind my avatar at a 45° angle.

How do I disable that? It's obnoxious and I just want to.

[image]

Comment: post a picture for better understanding

Comment: @Ruskes Done! Just typing more letters to meet the minimum character requirement for a comment.